# Deploy docker on AWS beanstalk with docker composer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy multiple node.js micro services on AWS beanstalk, and I want them to be deployed on the same instance. It's my first time to deploy multiple services, so there're some failures I need someone to help me out. So, I tried to package them in a docker container first. Meanwhile I'm using docker composer to manage the structure. It's up and running locally in my virtual machine, but when I deployed it on to beanstalk, I met a few problems.

What I know:

1. I know I have to choose to deploy as multi-container docker.
2. The best practice to manage multiple node.js services is using docker composer.
3. I need a `dockerrun.aws.json` for node.js app.
4. I need to create task definition for that ecs instance.

Where I have problems:

1. I can only find `dockerrun.aws.json` and `task_definition.json`
   template for php, so I can't verify if my configuration for node.js
   in those two json files are in correct shape.
2. It seems like `docker-compose.yml`, `dockerrun.aws.json` and `task_definition.json` are doing similar jobs. I must keep
   task_definition, but do I still need dockerrun.aws.json?
3. I tried to run the task in ecs, but it stopped right away. How can I check the log for the task?

I got:

> No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment

because my task will always stop immediately. If I can check the log, it will be much easier for me to do trouble shooting.

Here is my `task_definition.json`:

```
{
  "requiresAttributes": [],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:231440562752:task-definition/ComposerExample:1",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "revision": 1,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "memory": 100,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": null,
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
          "sourceVolume": "webdata",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ],
      "name": "nginxexpressredisnodemon_nginx_1",
      "ulimits": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "environment": [],
      "links": null,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "image": "nginxexpressredisnodemon_nginx",
      "command": null,
      "user": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "cpu": 99,
      "privileged": null
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/ecs/webdata"
      },
      "name": "webdata"
    }
  ],
  "family": "ComposerExample"
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/ingenieux/beanstalker/issues/63

Comment: @taco, this is not exactly what I'm looking for, but I might as well post my issue in this issue tracker, thanks.

Comment: And I'm not using their beanstalker

Comment: It seemed like a similair issue, but enough to be considered the right answer. Unfortunately, I'm not of much help with AWS.

Comment: Yes, they are fairly new technologies, any more ideas that I can make this question more generic so that more people can view this?

Comment: Hi I don't know if it will help but I had the same issue and mine was because my Dockerrun.aws.json file was not committed. EB client ignore (I guess) files that are not commited. Also, I think you don't need both files: Dockerrun.aws.json and task_definition.json. As you said they are doing the same job. I only used Dockerrun file and succeed to deploy a docker compose containing nodejs app and redis image. BR.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. What was your solution? As Nad1 said, we only need dockerrun.aws.json file which contains the docker container definitions. But I get an error stating no ECS task found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that I archived the containing folder directly in my Archive.zip file, thus giving me this structure in the Archive.zip file:

```
RootFolder
    - Dockerrun.aws.json
    - Other files...
```

It turned out that by archiving only the RootFolder's content (and not the folder itself), Amazon Beanstalk recognized the ECS Task Definition file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was simply a case of ensuring the name of the file matched the exact casing as described in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun).

`dockerfile.aws.json` had to be exactly `Dockerfile.aws.json`

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem. What fixed it for me was using the CLI tools instead of zipping myself, just running `eb deploy` worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me codecommit was no. Then after adding the Dockerrun.aws.json in git it works.

Answer (score 0):

I got here due to the error. What my issue was is that I was deploying with a label using:

```
eb deploy --label MY_LABEL
```

What you need to do is deploy with `'`:

```
eb deploy --label 'MY_LABEL'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well. For me the problem was that Dockerrun.aws.json wasn't added in git. `eb deploy` detects the presence of git.

I ran `eb deploy --verbose` to figure this out:

```
INFO: Getting version label from git with git-describe
INFO: creating zip using git archive HEAD
```

It further lists all the files that'll go in to the zip, Dockerrun.aws.json isn't there.

`git status` reports this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Dockerrun.aws.json

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Adding the file to git and committing helped.
In my specific case I could just remove the `.git` directory in a scripted deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had not committed the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file after creating it, so using `eb deploy` failed with the same error.